# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Library in java.library.path

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to Bundle a native library with my Eclipse plug-in. When I provide the path of the library with `-Djava.library.path`, it works perfect.

However, when I add it to the `MANIFEST.MF` file, it throws an exception that says,

`Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no XpNamedPipeJni in java.library.path`

The code in `MANIFEST.MF` is

`Bundle-NativeCode: lib/XpNamedPipeJni.dll; lib/XpNamedPipeJni_64.dll; osname=Win32; processor=x86; processor=x86-64, 
 lib/libXpNamedPipeJni.dylib; osname=MacOSX; processor=x86; processor=PowerPC; processor=x86-64`

The funny thing is, it works perfectly in Windows with `Bundle-NativeCode: lib/XpNamedPipeJni.dll; lib/XpNamedPipeJni_64.dll`. The problem comes when I add another line for Mac OS. I also tried `Bundle-NativeCode: lib/libXpNamedPipeJni.dylib`. Doesn't work.

I tried all probable permutations of OS/Processor values from [OSGi specifications here](http://www.osgi.org/Specifications/Reference).

Comment: How about using alias name "Mac OS X"?

Comment: It's strange. You can try to add line break for library of Mac OS X. And if your bundle only works on Eclipse/Equinox, you can put your libraries on below folder structure,

    --os

     --win32

       --x86

         --XpNamedPipeJni.dll

Comment: But the Mac library works on both x86 and x86_64 platforms. Do I create two folder structure as `os/macosx/x86/lib.dylib`, `os/macosx/x86_64/lib.dylib`?
PS. I added line breaks. No change.

Comment: Anyways, none of the above worked. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it solved. I was using the wrong extension of the library. I changed the extension from `dylib` to `jnilib` and it worked. Apparently, the Java VM on OS X seems to require the file extension be `.jnilib`. Any ideas about the reason behind this?

Now the code simply looks like

`Bundle-NativeCode: lib/XpNamedPipeJni.dll; osname=Win32; processor=x86,
 lib/XpNamedPipeJni_64.dll; osname=Win32; processor=x86_64,
 lib/libXpNamedPipeJni.jnilib; osname=macosx; processor=x86; processor=x86_64; processor=ppc`

Answer (score 0):

If your eclipse is not able to load XpNamedPipeJni.dylib (or any filename.dylib), its because eclipse is trying to load it from System by a call *System.loadLibrary(fileName)*  and eclipse is not able to find it from load locations as the file doesn't exist in these locations.

To see from where all eclipse try to load it, add following line in your code:

```
String locations = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
```

see all the locations and copy your file into any of these locations,(if location doesn't exist, create it and copy).
Restart the eclipse, it will work fine now.